# In spark UI, how to view the actual visual query plan of the computation which is cached?

Tags: apache-spark, caching

Below are 2 queries for the code

`import org.apache.spark.sql._`
`val columns = Seq("language","users_count")`
`val data = Seq(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000"))`
`val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)`
`val dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF("language","users_count")`
`val data1 = Seq(("Java"), ("Python"), ("Scala"))`
`val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1)`
`val dfFromRDD2 = rdd1.toDF("language")`

cached:-

### `dfFromRDD1.join(dfFromRDD2,dfFromRDD1.col("language").lt(dfFromRDD2.col("language")),"inner").cache().show()`

Without Caching:-
`dfFromRDD1.join(dfFromRDD2,dfFromRDD1.col("language").lt(dfFromRDD2.col("language")),"inner").show()`

---

We get a beautiful visual query plan for non cached computation but not for cached one.
Want to understand, how can we see the visual query plan for cached computation?

[Cached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrCU8.png)

[without caching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89C7.png)

Comment: Good question, i cannot find it to. I found only text representation. In case of long queries part of it is visible in storage tab (but only when your dataset is in cache, so when job finishes it may disappear). Full text representation can be found in SQL tab, in case of your first screen you can extends details and here you may find "InMemoryRelation" and its plan